# how to set the controls side by side in the panel

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

I have something like this:

[image]

but I need to set controls next to each other like this:

[image]

my Panel.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" 
Runat="Server">
<asp:Panel ID="pnlProducts" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
</asp:Content>
```

my Panel.aspx.cs

```
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        int id = row;

        byte[] bytes = (byte[])row["image"];
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        Panel productPanel = new Panel();
            ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton
            {
               ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + base64String,
               CssClass = "productImage",
               PostBackUrl = string.Format("Product1.aspx?id={0}", row)
            };
            Label lblName = new Label
            {
                Text = row["nazwa"].ToString(),
                CssClass = "productName"
            };
            Label lblPrice = new Label
           {
               Text = row["cena"].ToString() + " zl",
               CssClass = "productPrice"
            };

            productPanel.Controls.Add(imageButton);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br/>" });
            productPanel.Controls.Add(lblName);
            productPanel.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = "<br/>" });
            productPanel.Controls.Add(lblPrice);
            pnlProducts.Controls.Add(productPanel);
    }
}
```

my css code

```
/*Webshop */
   #ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlProducts div {
   float: left;
   width: 250px;
   height: 250px;
   text-align: center;
  }

.productName {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 18px;

 }

    .productPrice {
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    color: #FFB600;
    }

  .productImage {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    vertical-align: central;
    padding: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 50px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
   border-radius: 50px;
 }
```

I dont know where I have to use float:Left or somethinthing like that how to set the controls side by side in the panel.

Comment: `float: left` is completely unnecessary here. elements default to `display: block` which "encourages" them to occupy as much horizontal space as possible. to counteract this, give each `productPanel` the `display: inline` or `display: table-cell` property

Answer (score 0):

You should use Flex-box it's very easy

On your parent :

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

And on the child:

```
flex: 1 1 20%;
```

Comment: Unfortunately but: "flew-wrap" is not a known CSS property name.

Comment: @Tprogramer1 it is `flex-wrap`

Comment: #ContentPlaceHolder1_pnlProducts div {
    .......
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.productName {
    flex: 1 1 20%;
}

.productPrice {
    flex: 1 1 20%;
}

.productImage {
        flex: 1 1 20%; }
It still does not work.

Comment: @Tprogramer1 are you using IE7 ?

Comment: Do you have any margin on your child ?

Comment: I have no any margin on my child

Comment: Can you do a JS Fiddle with your code and google inspector element ?